# Install shapely in Docker - OSError: Could not find library c or load any of its variants []

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, shapely

I am trying to install shapely in docker container and when trying to build it, I had an error:

```
OSError: Could not find library c or load any of its variants []
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
RUN apk add geos-dev
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv utils/geojson/venv
#GEOS_CONFIG=/path/to/geos-config pip install shapely
#RUN apk add python3.6-venv
#RUN python3 -m venv utils/geojson/venv
RUN pip install -r utils/geojson/requirements.txt
CMD python
```

and requirements.txt:

```
pip>=18
setuptools>=40
shapely>=1.6.4
```

What I am missed?.. Please help me

## EDIT:

I don't know exactly how I can use GEOS_CONFIG and LD_LIBRARY_PATH... (that was suggested)

Comment: did you try to specify the environment variable `GEOS_CONFIG=/path/to/geos-config` as mentioned [on this page](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/)? Or maybe you have to define the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Please don’t paste images of text into SO questions.  While you’ve included the key details, it’s much better to paste the contents of your Dockerfile and requirements file as plain text: it’s more searchable, can be copied out for local reproductions, and works for people who can’t see the images.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, Do you know where I am to specify /path/to/geos-config? I don't know how I can use it in Dockerfile

Comment: @DavidMaze, I edited my question, sorry for images

Comment: Take a look at docker [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) command.

Comment: Uh, but what is the path/to/geos-config? and LD_LIBRARY_PATH... I am new to building docker containers